# Fresh Install of Ubuntu 16.04.1 on Formatted Drive Black Screen After Boot-Repair

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, boot-repair, nomodeset

I'm brand new to Linux and I'm so, so very confused on what I could have done wrong when I installed my OS. I have formatted my hard drive so this install of Linux should be a fresh install. Since I have an NVidia discrete GPU on this laptop, I used the GRUB "nomodeset" option to boot into Ubuntu using a pendrive. After installing Linux and trying to boot from my hard drive, a series of lines flash across the screen very quickly then a black screen with an underscore in the upper left-hand corner appears. Venturing a guess, this means that GRUB is not booting properly from my hard drive.

I used Boot-Repair's automatic setting to try and repair the problem but to no avail. Attached is the pastebin log of my specific error: http://paste2.org/sOwXAEeD . Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to use nomodeset until you install proprietary drivers. http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers  If you only get command line/terminal. `ubuntu-drivers devices` then: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: It sounds like you're getting to the GRUB menu, and selecting Ubuntu, yes? The key is the series of lines that flash across the screen too fast to read. Take your smartphone camera app, set to macro mode, and make a video of these startup lines. Then go back and view the video to get the clues of what the lines say, and what the error might be. Post the error lines here if you'd like help with them. Cheers, Al